# It's too good a position for him to let go

Tags: prepositions

I was looking at one of the sentence in my textbook and I just wondered if this sentence is correct:

> It's too good a position for him to let go.

Isn't

> It's such a good position for him to let go

sound better?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I can't find the links to back me up, so it's just a gut feeling: both sentences are correct, but they mean different things and probably also use different meanings of the word "position".

"It's too good a position for him to let go" means that he would not leave his position (≈post), it's too good.
"It's such a good position for him to let go" means that he's in a good position (≈condition) to let go of past and move on.

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence is definitely correct. : )
It's a slightly fancy construction. It means "the position is too good for him to let go", basically.

I'm not sure if your version is right... Well, Roux mentions an interpretation that makes it an okay sentence, but it definitely doesn't mean the same thing.